# What's the difference between 去年 and 昨年?

Tags: nuances

I learned 去年 well before 昨年, so I just always use 去年 out of habit. But now I'm wondering if they really are interchangeable or if there's even a subtle difference that would make one more appropriate in some situations over the other.

So are they interchangeable, or does a subtle difference exist?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

去年 can be used in almost any situation. 昨年 is more formal and not good for casual conversation.

For example,

> 1) 去年、結婚いたしました。
>   2) 昨年、結婚いたしました。

2) is better because いたしました is a humble form but 1) is totally acceptable. On the other hand,

> 1) 去年、結婚しちゃった
>   2) 昨年、結婚しちゃった

1) is natural but 2) sounds a bit strange.

The same applies to:

> 昨日{きのう} vs. 昨日{さくじつ} (yesterday; the same kanji but read differently)

**前年{ぜんねん}** is a similar word and it means '**previous year**'.

> 大統領{だいとうりょう}選挙{せんきょ}の前年は、株価{かぶか}が上がる。
>   Stock prices rise in a pre-presidential election year.

前年 is often used to compare a certain year with the previous year.

> 前年比{ぜんねんひ} 50%増{ぞう}
>   Up 50% over the previous year

Without reference to another year, 前年 means 'last year' and it is used almost always to compare 'last year' with 'this current year'.

> 1) 息子が生まれる前年に、結婚しました。(I got married in the year before my son was born.)
>   2) 前年、結婚しました .

1) is natural. 2) sounds incomplete because it doesn't compare anything or specify the reference year.

Answer (score 2):

From what my teacher told me, 去年{きょねん} and 昨年｛さくねん｝mean the same thing, but 昨年 sounds more sophisticated.

I would guess that depending on the situation they may or may not be interchangeable with the difference being who your audience is.

*There may be a situation where this specifically is the case, but I am not aware of it, someone more knowledgeable than I will have to answer as to whether or not this is the case.*